VB6 option to "Make EXE" is missing
I still use the VB6 IDE for some projects, but as of today the menu option "File... Make EXE" is greyed out. This isn't specific to one project -- no current or past project will compile to EXE from within the IDE on this machine.
I can compile from the command line using VB6 /make, so I'm not totally SOL, but it's an inconvenience and a mystery.
I can't find this issue mentioned here or on the wider web, so I'm hoping someone here has an idea.

Does this answer your question? File -> Make... menu option is disabled in VB6 IDE

@StayOnTarget - Sorry, as mentioned in a removed comment, that was the first thing I tried. I must have done it wrong, though, because it didn't help. Trying it again, as TheNomad suggested, did.

Jim - glad it worked out! Defnitely a weird & frustrating issue that everyone runs into eventually :(    Best to mark this question a dupe of the other one for future readers too.

To fix it, reset the menus & toolbars by going to View->Toolbars->Customize->Reset
